# Text datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one variable `email_body` in my database and it is defined as `text` datatype. When I check the values which are stored in `email_body`, it is in the form of html.

Can anybody tell me how it is storing in html format?

for e.g.

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
  <span style="color: black; font-family:&quot;tim&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
    <span style="font-size:small;">Hi,</span>
  </span>
</p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
  <span style="color: black;font-family:&quot;tim&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
    <br />
    <span style="font-size: small;">Here is the weekly check register for the week of MM-DD-YY</span>
  </span>
</p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
  <span style="color: black;font-family:&quot;tim&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
    <span style="font-size:small;">&nbsp;</span>
  </span>
</p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
   <span style="color: black;font-family:&quot;tim&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
      <span style="font-size: small;">If you have any questions, please feel free to contact us.</span>
   </span>
</p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
  <span style="color: black;font-family:&quot;tim&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
     <span style="font-size:small;">&nbsp;</span>
  </span>
</p> 
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">
  <span style="color: black;font-family:&quot;tim&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
     <span style="font-size: small;">Please <strong><span style="text-decoration:underline;">
        <span style="font-family: &quot;tim&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">reply to all</span>
     </span></strong> when responding to this email.</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Which database do you use? I don't think TEXT is standard SQL type. Also HTML is a text after all.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276838%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

*note that the Text Datatype has become [obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) and has been superseded by the VARCHAR(MAX) datatype.*

> **text**
>
> Variable-length non-Unicode data in
>   the code page of the server and with a
>   maximum length of 231-1
>   (2,147,483,647) characters. When the
>   server code page uses double-byte
>   characters, the storage is still
>   2,147,483,647 bytes. Depending on the
>   character string, the storage size may
>   be less than 2,147,483,647 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

what is your problem exactly ? do you store them in html-format or cant ? even html-format is in fact kind of xml format so that you may store it directly as an xml type, too. morely if you want to show that html-formatted data in your browser you may use a label. Assing html as a string to label.text property.